# Is have been enrolled or have enrolled correct?

Tags: american-english

Which one is correct?

> I have enrolled in this course.

> I have been enrolled in this course.

Comment: Either may be correct, depending on the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can both be correct—as can be some variations:

1. I **have** enrolled in this course. I signed up online. [You enrolled yourself.]
2. I **have** ***been*** enrolled in this course. [Somebody else enrolled you.]
3. I **have** ***been*** enrolled in this course *for a month now*. [Somebody enrolled you a month ago, but it could have been you or somebody else who did it.]
4. I **was** enrolled in this course. My friend signed me up online. [Somebody else enrolled you.]
5. I **was** enrolled in this course. But then I realized it wasn't for me, and I dropped it. [Somebody enrolled you, but it could have been you or somebody else who did it.]

Note that 2. and 3. are very similar, and it's only the context that would more commonly have 2. mean that somebody else enrolled you. (Normally, if we don't give a timeline, that's how we take it.)

Also note that 4. and 5. are identical, except for the sentences that follow, each providing a different possible meaning.

---

In short, which of the two variations in the question would normally be used depends on what, specifically, is being expressed—and also if there is more than just the one sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Enrolling in a course usually requires two actions - 1a) by you providing information and paying money, 1b) by someone else providing information and paying money for you, and 2) by someone official accepting your or the other person's information or money. If the emphasis in on what you do (1a), then you would probably say 'I enrolled'. If the emphasis is on what someone else did (1b) or (2), then you would probably say 'I was enrolled'.